# How to convert ASCII string to UTF-8 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert an ASCII string to UTF-8 with javascript.

So the following raw ASCII strings:

```
imagￃﾨ-thrￃﾩￃﾪ.png
imￃﾤge-twￃﾶ.png
ￃﾬmￃﾡgￃﾩ-fￃﾲￃﾻr.png
```

Needs to be converted to:

```
imäge-twö.png
imagè-thréê.png
ìmágé-fòûr.png
```

I can do it with this [online utility](https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-ascii-to-utf8) (so it's possible!). Looking for a way to do it with a javascript function.

Comment: What is the source of the raw strings, e.g., pasted text, from a file or database, etc.

Comment: In Node.js: `Buffer.from(text, 'ascii').toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use this [utf-8](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js) library for that. If you are using plain `javaScript` you need to save the `utf-8.js` file and use it in `<script src="">` tag. Then you can use`utf8.decode()` function.
Something like:

```
<body>
    <script src="./utf-8.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log(utf8.decode('imagￃﾨ-thrￃﾩￃﾪ.png'))
        console.log(utf8.decode('imￃﾤge-twￃﾶ.png'))
        console.log(utf8.decode('ￃﾬmￃﾡgￃﾩ-fￃﾲￃﾻr.png'))
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome! This did the trick!